# RDP connections never end

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I'm using RDP to connect to a server via Bozteck VENM Console. One of my servers always greets me with "Connect to existing Remote Desktop" and has 2 active sessions with the PC.

[image]

This doesn't happen on other PCs I RDP into, just a single test server. How can I kill these active connections, and how can I  make sure my connection ends when I stop using it? I've tried using the Disconnect Session option before closing the RDP window in VENM Console, it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Disconnect session does exactly what you are trying to avoid - it disconnects you without logging you off.  If you make sure you always log off rather than just disconnecting, this shouldn't happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window you have is because you disconnected two sessions without logout: you just closed the RDP window, or the connection get lost for a reason or another. This is not a problem at all.

Just connect twice to your server.
First connection will show the image you have. Don't disconnect. Second connection will not ask anything. Then you can disconnect both.

If you want your disconnected session being automatically trashed... well, this is not a good idea, because it can be usefull. For example you launch a lenghty operation. For whatever reason you disconnect (because you start at your office and you continue at home, because your DSL line get broken, because etc), so later you can connect back.

If you really want that, you have to go to configure your RDP server to close the session upon delai expiration (I don't have any server localised in english, so I don't know the wording used. If anyone could complete...).

Comment: This seems to work, I can just log off when I need to. But why does it end up with two sessions? I should be the only one RDPing into this server regularly.